# Change Pandas date column format from "MMDDYYYY" to "YYYY-MM-DD"

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Example: 10011933 to 1933-10-01

**Here's my data in a Pandas DataFrame:**

date
10011933
04041961
07061931
10281988

**My attempt to solve:**

```
df['date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%Y%m%d')
```

**Error Message - I get the following error:**

ValueError: unconverted data remains: 57

How would I correct to remove the error? Thanks.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%m%d%Y')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert string date (Jan 25, 2021) to y-m-d date (2021-01-01) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65894575/how-to-convert-string-date-jan-25-2021-to-y-m-d-date-2021-01-01-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

First parse the string column into a datetime

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%d%m%Y')
```

Then format the datetime into a string of your desired format

```
df['date_formatted'] = df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Or you can do it all in one line if you desire

Comment: Thanks. This gives me "ValueError: unconverted data remains: 7". It seems like a similar error I was experiencing.

Comment: I'm able to remove the error by adding "errors='coerce'" to pd.to_datetime but now there's lots of blanks on the output.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise that it was month-day-year to start. Just switch the '%d%m%Y' in the first line to '%m%d%Y'

Comment: Thanks. That gives "19331001", how do I add the dashes?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution:

```
df['date_new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%m%d%Y').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Where df['date_new'] gives the desired output

```
0    1933-10-01
1    1961-04-04
2    1931-07-06
3    1988-10-28
```